# A sectional macro that adds lines above/below the title

Tags: sectioning, rules

I want to add two rule before and after `\tenbai`. Can somebody help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{
    \addtocounter{sobai}{1}
    \textbf{\centerline{\huge{\S\thesobai. #1}}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai. #1}
}


\begin{document}

    \tenbai{Số phức và tính toán đại số}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Be aware of spurious spaces in your definition. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: Maybe this helps: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{sobai}%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill
  \begin{center}
    \huge\bfseries \S\thesobai.~#1%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai.~#1}%
  \end{center}
  \hrulefill\par
}

\begin{document}

\tenbai{Số phức và tính toán đại số}

\end{document}` (each `%` is immediately followed by an end-of-line). Maybe it would be better to use for instance `titlesec` and redefine the appearance of sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option - setting the header inside a `tabular` that spans the entire `\linewidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\newcounter{sobai}
\newcommand{\tenbai}[1]{%
  \par
  \stepcounter{sobai}%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
    \hline \hline
    \hfill\bfseries\huge\strut \S\thesobai. #1\hfill\mbox{} \\
    \hline \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\S\thesobai. #1}%
  \par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}

\tenbai{Số phức và tính toán đại số}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use standard tools such as `titlesec`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}% mock text

\titleformat{\section}
 {\huge\bfseries\filcenter\titlerule}
 {\S\thesection.}
 {0.33333em}
 {}
 [\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Số phức và tính toán đại số}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Số thực}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]